# Qual a melhor forma de buscar muitas variáveis no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, linq

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação C# MVC e estou tendo problemas para apresentar os registros. Tenho uma lista com mais de 250 variáveis e o usuário escolhe qual delas quer ver no gráfico. Dentro do controller eu faço um switch case para o LINQ de cada variável da lista. O problema é que sempre dá erro System.StackOverflowException depois que passo de 200 variáveis. Existe alguma forma mais inteligente de fazer essa busca no SQL?

```
switch (tipoDados) {
case "Temperatura Ar de Combustão":
                    var pffeifer = db.PffeiferPRODs.Where(p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.Data_coleta) >= data1 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.Data_coleta) <= data2).OrderBy(p => p.Data_coleta).ToArray();
                    var dataTabela = pffeifer.Select(p => p.Data_coleta).Distinct().ToArray();
                    max = new double[dataTabela.Length]; min = new double[dataTabela.Length]; mediana = new double[dataTabela.Length]; quartil1 = new double[dataTabela.Length]; quartil3 = new double[dataTabela.Length];
                    for (int a = 0; a < dataTabela.Length; a++)
                    {
                        DateTime data = dataTabela[a];
                        int q1 = 0, q3 = 0;
                        double cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0;
                        var varDia = pffeifer.Where(p => p.Data_coleta == data).OrderBy(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao).ToArray();

                        //pega o máximo e o minimo
                        try
                        {
                            max[a] = varDia.OrderBy(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao).Max(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao);
                            min[a] = varDia.OrderBy(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao).Min(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            max[a] = 0;
                            min[a] = 0;
                        }

                        if (varDia.Length % 2 != 0) //se o tamanho do array for impar
                        {
                            int pos = (varDia.Length + 1) / 2;
                            mediana[a] = varDia[pos - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;

                            if (((pos - 1) % 2) != 0) // se o tamanho dos quartis for ímpar
                            {
                                q1 = Convert.ToInt32((varDia.Length + 1) * 0.25);
                                quartil1[a] = varDia[q1 - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;

                                q3 = Convert.ToInt32((varDia.Length + 1) * 0.75);
                                quartil3[a] = varDia[q3 - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                            }
                            else //se o tamanho dos quartis for par
                            {
                                q1 = Convert.ToInt32((varDia.Length - 1) * 0.25);
                                try
                                {
                                    cont1 = varDia[q1 - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                {
                                    cont1 = varDia[q1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                cont2 = varDia[q1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                quartil1[a] = (cont1 + cont2) / 2;

                                q3 = Convert.ToInt32((varDia.Length) * 0.75);
                                cont1 = varDia[q3 - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                try
                                {
                                    cont2 = varDia[q3].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                {
                                    if (q3 < 0)
                                    {
                                        q3 = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        q3 = q3 - 1;
                                    }
                                    cont2 = varDia[q3].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                quartil3[a] = (cont1 + cont2) / 2;
                            }
                        }
                        else // se o tamanho for par
                        {
                            //se 10
                            int pos1 = varDia.Length / 2;
                            int pos2 = (varDia.Length / 2) - 1;
                            if (pos1 < 0)
                            {
                                pos1 = 0;
                            }
                            if (pos2 < 0)
                            {
                                pos2 = 0;
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                mediana[a] = (varDia[pos1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao + varDia[pos2].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao) / 2;
                            }
                            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                            {
                                mediana[a] = 0;
                            }

                            if ((pos1 % 2) != 0) // se o tamanho dos quartis for ímpar
                            {
                                q1 = Convert.ToInt32(pos1 / 2) - 1;
                                if (q1 < 0)
                                {
                                    q1 = 0;
                                }
                                quartil1[a] = varDia[q1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;

                                q3 = Convert.ToInt32((pos1 / 2) + (varDia.Length / 2)) - 1;
                                if (q3 < 0)
                                {
                                    q3 = 0;
                                }
                                quartil3[a] = varDia[q3].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                            }
                            else //se o tamanho dos quartis for par
                            {
                                q1 = Convert.ToInt32(pos1 / 2);
                                try
                                {
                                    cont1 = varDia[q1 - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                {
                                    cont1 = 0;
                                }
                                try
                                {
                                    cont2 = varDia[q1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                {
                                    cont2 = 0;
                                }

                                quartil1[a] = (cont1 + cont2) / 2;

                                q3 = Convert.ToInt32((pos1 / 2) + (varDia.Length / 2));
                                try
                                {
                                    cont1 = varDia[q3 - 1].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                {
                                    cont1 = 0;
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    cont2 = varDia[q3].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                }
                                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                {
                                    if (q3 < 0)
                                    {
                                        q3 = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        q3 = q3 - 1;
                                    }
                                    try
                                    {
                                        cont2 = varDia[q3].Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao;
                                    }
                                    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                                    {
                                        cont2 = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                                quartil3[a] = (cont1 + cont2) / 2;
                            }
                        }
                        mdia = varDia.Average(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao);
                        listaDia.Add(Convert.ToString(dataTabela[a].ToShortDateString()));
                        listaDados.Add(new BoxplotSeriesData { Y = Math.Round(mdia, 2), Q1 = Math.Round(quartil1[a], 2), Q3 = Math.Round(quartil3[a], 2), Median = Math.Round(mediana[a], 2), Low = Math.Round(min[a], 2), High = Math.Round(max[a], 2) });
                    }

                    media = pffeifer.Average(p => p.Temp_arcombustao_camcombustao);
                    break;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi, você tem 250 cases desse? Acho que vai ser necessário repensar a sua estrutura como um todo

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem a exceção `System.StackOverflowException` é porque está a ter muitas chamadas na pilha de execução. Isso não deverá ter relação com o teu `switch` (que nada mais é que uma sequência de `IF`s). O erro muito provavelmente ocorre por conta de um loop (for/foreach/while).